# inner join no funciona

Tags: php, sql, join

**Este es mi codigo de consulta**

```
SELECT nombre_rol FROM usuarios INNER JOIN rol ON (id_rol=fk_rol)
```

**Este es mi codigo para la consulta**

```
<tr>
   <td>
       <?php echo $consulta['nombre_rol'];?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

y me aparece error en la linea de la consulta

Comment: Podrias añadir la estructura de tu base de datos para poder entender las relaciones entre tus tablas?

Comment: Pues parece que olvidaste incluir la columna en el código de la consulta que esperar leer desde php.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias agregar mas contexto a esta pregunta.. si no, imposible saber que pasa

Comment: Y cuando tenes un error, agrega que error tenes...

Comment: Nos ayudaría a ayudarte que indiques el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a crear una consulta con _INNER JOIN_ cuando vas a obtener solo un campo. En todo caso sería algo como `SELECT usuarios.*, rol.nombre_rol FROM usuarios INNER JOIN rol ON (id_rol=fk_rol) WHERE condicion`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te arroja? ¿Explícitamente?

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista, y sin poder ver la consulta (ya que aún no la posteas), eso de "me marca error en la línea de la consulta", me parece que es porque te falta un espacio entre `echo` y  `$consulta['nombre_rol'];`, así:

```php
<?php echo $consulta['nombre_rol'];?>
```

Comment: La consulta esta agregada a la pregunta, lo que necesitamos es ver la relación de las tablas de la DB.